# How to transform a invalid XML to a well-formed XML

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd, transform, dtd

I'm trying to transform a XML with XSLT to html, but my XML is not valid to the XSLT because it has invalid caracters like `&Oacute;`.

I can't modify my XML, because it is generated by others.
This is an example of the XML file:

```
<contrato>      
    <p  style="margin: 0px; line-height: 1.4em; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: Aniifont, Arial, sans-serif;">            
      <strong>CONDICIONES DE OTORGAMIENTO DE INCENTIVO ECON&Oacute;MICO
            SISTEMA NACIONAL DE INVESTIGADORES.</strong> 
    </p> 
</contrato>
```

I need to transform the original XML to other without these special caracters and I have no idea how to do it.

Thanks you in advance.

Comment: There is an entity reference `&Oacute;` in there, to be able to parse that input as XML you need your document to declare the entity in a DTD. Do you have a DTD for that snippet? Also which XSLT processor do you use or can you use, it seems the content of that `contrato` element is an HTML fragment so it might be possible to preprocess that sample as XHTML with HTMLTidy or similar.

Comment: I'll try your second advise. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Well, use an (X)HTML parser like http://saxonica.com/html/documentation9.7/functions/saxon/parse-html.html would do with e.g. `saxon:parse-html(unparsed-text('your-input.xml'))` or as I said you can do outside of XML/XSLT by using e.g. http://www.html-tidy.org/.